# C# Graphics.RotateTransform works on localhost, but not on remote server

Tags: c#, graphics, web-config, shared-hosting, machine.config

It works on my machine...

I have a problem with using a C# Graphics method on my ASP.NET web host.

I'm combining two map pins into a single image. I load an empty pin image and write a number on top of it. I then combine two of these, having rotated one 15 degrees and the other -15 degrees. It looks fine running through my localhost web server:

[Expected http://harriyott.com/images/stackoverflow/expected.png](http://harriyott.com/images/stackoverflow/expected.png)

I upload this to my shared server, and I get this instead:

[Actual http://harriyott.com/images/stackoverflow/actual.png](http://harriyott.com/images/stackoverflow/actual.png)

I load the image thus:

```
var g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
```

The line to rotate the image is:

```
g.RotateTransform(angle);
```

I'm sure this must be a setting somewhere, but I've had no luck finding it.

Comment: I have experienced similar issues with bitmap conversion in .NET.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389213/net-3-5-web-app-c-image-scaling-on-the-fly-lower-quality-on-deployed-site-v . It works one way in development, but deployed to Windows Server 2003 results in completely different image quality / attributes, so we had to write code to explicitly set things. Both have .NET 3.5 SP1. Never actually found an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you still have the file stream to load the image open when you do the rotate on it, as it is likely to be accessing the original image to perform a transformation on it.

Not sure if that will solve this one, but worth a shot!

Comment: Thanks for answering. As it works fine on my machine, would this affect the remote one?